# Outlook supplies an expired Exchange token to an add-in

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

We develop an Outlook add-in which is supposed to get an Exchange token internally through Office.js API for validation. What we've noticed is that if you leave Outlook (desktop) open for a long time (overnight for example) and then try to open your add-in, an expired token is supplied which our add-in fails to validate. Is this an Outlook (desktop) bug?

Comment: Can you clarify something, are you seeing this behaviour when you re-open the addin? Or did you left open overnight and you're seeing problems?

Comment: Mavi, Outlook itself has been open for a while. Then either scenario: click something in an open add-in or close/re-open add-in. Add-in gets a valid but expired token which our own validation code would reject.

Comment: Mavi, any updates here?

Comment: Wanted to understand more about the scenario. Are you trying this addin in read mode or compose mode? User identity token has expiration time of 480 minutes. After that outlook expires the token and issues a fresh token. Just wanted to make sure that you are making a call to Outlook to get identity token and are not caching it at the client side.
We are also trying to reproduce the issue at our end.

Comment: Hi Deepak. I see it in a read mode for sure and our add-in restarts and gets the identity token anew when a user clicks our command button. But the returned token is expired. For a while I thought this was fixed by an Outlook update but in the last couple of days this behavior repeated.